# Python Regex - A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract a certrain string from a path. The wanted string is always preceded by either `\0_ASW\` or `\10_BSW\` words. Additionally, the sought string consists of only letters and numbers.

So for example from the following 3 paths I want to extract strings `Mod2000`, `ModA` and `ModB`:

```
C:\MyPath\0_ASW\Mod2000
C:\MyPath\10_BSW\ModA\SubDir
C:\MyPath\10_BSW\ModB
```

For that I have written a regex using Positive Lookbehind:

```
\\(?<=(0_ASW|10_BSW)\\)([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

With this regex the 2nd group matches the sought string correctly and I am able to compile the regex in **.NET(C#)** without any errors. However, once I try to compile it in Python I get the following Regex Error: `A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width`

From my understanding, the two words in the positive lookbehind, i.e. `0_ASW`  and `10_BSW` ought to have the fixed length. The error is not clear to me because both words have a fixed length of 4 and 5 characters, respectively. If I try to make those 2 strings to have equal length, e.g. 3 character strings `ASW` and `BSW`, the regex compiles without the above error.

```
\\(?<=(ASW|BSW)\\)([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

How do I fix this regex so that it compiles in Python as well?

You can find the demos here:

https://regex101.com/r/qfwfJJ/1

https://regex101.com/r/zAVk5Z/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead like this with an alternation, as for Python it has to be fixed width which they are not in your pattern.

```
\b(?:(?<=\\0_ASW\\)|(?<=\\10_BSW\\))[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2uaETm/1).

---

If you can make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you match what you want then then you can use `\K` to forget what is matches so far:

```
\\(?:0_ASW|10_BSW)\\\K[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2uaETm/1).

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions):

```
\\(?:0_ASW|10_BSW)\\(\w+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hYCRJf/1

If the regex matches, you'll get the desired string in `group(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\\((0_ASW|10_BSW)\\)([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/e7vH34/1

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to use a regex with positive lookbehind that would still give a match?